# Qt 4.8. Painting radian-coords objects on top of the QPixmap geo map

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, coordinate-transformation, qt4.8

I'm trying to paint objects with radian coords on top of the QPixmap geo map.

```
QRectF zone( QPointF( 0.86459    , 1.8675)
           , QPointF( 0.86459+0.1, 1.8675+0.1));

QGraphicsScene gs;
gs.setParent( w.graphicsView()); //it's my QGraphicsView widget
gs.setSceneRect( zone);
w.graphicsView()->setScene( gs);

QGraphicsItem * gpi

  = gs.addPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage( QImage( "map.jpg"))); //For test reasons it's an red square (200x200)

//Let's paint a green line from bottom-left to top-right:
gs.addLine( 0.86459    , 1.8675
          , 0.86459+0.1, 1.8675+0.1, QPen( Qt::green));

w.graphicsView()->scale( 2000
                       , 2000); //as we want zone to correspond 200x200 square
w.graphicsView()->rotate( -90); //as geo coords are rotated

w.graphicsView()->setScene( &gs);

/*1*///    gpi->setFlag( QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);

gpi->setTransform( QTransform::fromScale( 1/2000
                                        , 1/2000)); //makes QPixmap size 0.1x0.1

gpi->setTransform( QTransform::fromTranslate( 0.86459
                                            , 1.8675), true);
```

The trouble is that I got green line displayed, not the map red square. If line /**1**/ is uncommented with respect to the next two lines, I got only green line too.

Comment: First `gpi->setTransform` call has no effect because it's overridden by the second call. Second `w.graphicsView()->setScene(&gs)` call also has no effect because the same scene has been already set.

Comment: Are you sure the image is successfully loaded ?

Comment: @Ilya, yes, it's loaded.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Isn't **combine** argument of the *setTransform* matters?